# C array of array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In C, I need to statically pre-allocate an array of numbers, each associated with a different array of strings. Will a code like the following do the trick:

```
struct number_and_strings {
  int  nnn;
  char **sss;
}

static struct number_and_strings my_list[] = {
  {12, {"apple","banana","peach","apricot","orange",NULL}},
  {34, {"tomato","cucumber",NULL}},
  {5,  {"bread","butter","cheese",NULL}},
  {79, {"water",NULL}}
}
```

Comment: Why don't try out and see?

Comment: What I fear is that it will seem to work, but due to some misunderstanding of pointers I will end up gulping or leaking memory.

Comment: The pointers will point at memory locations in the data segment. No leaking there.

Comment: No, it will not work. An array is not a pointer, so you can't initialize a pointer to pointer with an initializer for array of string.

Answer (score 5):

`sss` is a pointer to pointer. So an array of pointers can't be directly assigned to it. You can assign as follows using compound literals (which is a C99 feature):

```
static struct number_and_strings my_list[] = {
      {12, (char*[]){"apple","banana","peach","apricot","orange",NULL}},
      {34, (char*[]){"tomato","cucumber",NULL}},
      {5,  (char*[]){"bread","butter","cheese",NULL}},
      {79, (char*[]){"water",NULL}}
    };
```

Comment: This is not a cast, but something quite different, namely a compound literal. (C jargon and syntax for an unnamed object)

Comment: @FreeBud No, AFAIK C89/90 doesn't support it (but gcc supports it as an extension). If you compile in C99 mode, it should be fine. For example, if you are using gcc, then: `gcc -std=c99 file.c`.

Comment: Let me ask that differently: What changes can I put in the struct definition (or other changes), in order for the static array to be declared this way (or similarly), using ANSI C?

Comment: @FreeBud What is the compiler that you are you using? First directly copy the struct declaration in my answer and try.

Comment: >> What is the compiler that you are you using
-- it's tricky. I'm using Digital Mars C on my Windows PC, but the ultimate destination is to be included as part of an Objective C code on an Apple.

Comment: Well then you can keep these strings in an array and malloc for the struct variable and then assign these strings to struct variable in a loop.